# Swift function that can return various types

Tags: swift

Is it possible for a function to return a specific Data Type based on the parameter entered?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

I've defined different datatypes that will hold data from an API call

```
struct DataType1: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct DataType2: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct DataType3: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

let type1 = [DataType1(id: 0, name: "Kirk"),
             DataType1(id: 1, name: "Spock"),
             DataType1(id: 2, name: "McKoy"),
             DataType1(id: 3, name: "Sulu"),
             DataType1(id: 4, name: "Chekov"),
             DataType1(id: 5, name: "Uhura"),
             DataType1(id: 6, name: "Scott")]

let type2 = [DataType2(id: 0, name: "Picard"),
             DataType2(id: 1, name: "Riker"),
             DataType2(id: 2, name: "Data"),
             DataType2(id: 3, name: "Worf"),
             DataType2(id: 4, name: "La Forge"),
             DataType2(id: 5, name: "Crusher"),
             DataType2(id: 6, name: "Troi")]

let type3 = [DataType3(id: 0, name: "Sisko"),
             DataType3(id: 1, name: "Nerys"),
             DataType3(id: 2, name: "Dax"),
             DataType3(id: 3, name: "Odo"),
             DataType3(id: 4, name: "Bashir"),
             DataType3(id: 5, name: "O'Brien"),
             DataType3(id: 6, name: "Quark")]
```

I have a list view that will display the data based on a conditional. I've looked into different solutions like Generics and enums, but I can't get anything that addresses my specific problem.

I'm trying to write a function like:

```
func getCrew(show: String) {
    switch show {
    case "Star Trek: TOS":
        return type1
    case "Star Trek: The Next Generation":
        return type2
    case "Star Trek: Deep Space Nine":
        return type3
    default:
        return nil
    }
}

for type in getCrew(show: "Star Trek: TOS") {
    print(type.name)
}
```

Too get an output like:

```
// Kirk
// Spock
// McKoy
// Sulu
// Chekov
// Uhura
// Scott
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is the purpose of creating three types with identical content?

Comment: I don’t see any return type in getCrew function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use protocols:

Create protocol with given fields, and make all DataType1,2 etc classes conform to it:

```
protocol DataType {
    var id: Int {get set}
    var name: String {get set}
}

struct DataType1: DataType, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct DataType2: DataType, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

struct DataType3: DataType, Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}
```

Add DataType protocol as a return type to your function "getCrew":

```
func getCrew(show: String) -> [DataType]? {
    switch show {
    case "Star Trek: TOS":
        return type1
    case "Star Trek: The Next Generation":
        return type2
    case "Star Trek: Deep Space Nine":
        return type3
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Use iteration over the result:

```
for type in getCrew(show: "Star Trek: TOS") ?? [] {
    print(type.name)
}
```

---

PS It seems wrong using three different classes with same fields and logic. Why not having one *DataType* class for all your data?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your all data type is same. You can use same data with extra one property, just like below

```
struct DataType3: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var dataType: Int//1,2,3
}
```

By the way, you can use generics to allow different type with the same function. [Generics in Swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html)